# Why the clip property only works on elements with position: absolute or position: fixed

Tags: css

Why the clip property only works on elements with position: absolute or position: fixed. Why it won’t work with relative or static positioning.
heres is my code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr7Zp/)

```
<span>Hover me</span>
<img src="http://sambuh.com/assets/images/news%20headlines/bukhara-autumn1.jpg">



img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  display: block;
  clip: rect(200px, 0, 0, 400px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

span:hover ~ img {
  clip: rect(0px, 400px, 400px, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it doesn't.  The spec [says so](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping).

*Why* the spec says so is a very different question that I don't have an answer to  :)

Answer (score 2):

For your question need to understand the difference between various css positioning properties.

Here is some Useful Links:

1. [CSS clip properties with various positions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)
2. [Difference b/w CSS Positions](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)
3. [Practical Explanation of CSS Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

`clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0)` is deprecated, you should use: `clip-path:inset(0 0 0 0)`, it works with relative positioning.